# TypeNotSerializable Arguments: Exception in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

We have an application in Silverlight ,WCF RIA and Entity Framework.
Ever since i added a property to a class in the back end which is of type `List<string>` 
we are getting the error below sometimes, in Production Environment

```
[TypeNotSerializable] Arguments: System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d__99`1[System.String] Debugging resource strings are unavailable.
```

I tried including a `[KnownType(typeof(List<string>))]`, but still we are getting this error occasionally. Please let me know how to get rid of this error.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear someone is using `IEnumerable.Except` and not calling `.ToList` which is causing the iterator to still be in the structure when it is being serialized.

Comment: Thanks.. Never thought about it !